# OL3 load source-files for development

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to make some changes to ol3 (ol.format.WFS2 and ol.format.CityGML), for querying a WFS 2.0 which returns CityGML.

I cannot find however how I can include the openlayers source files into my dev application.

Currently I use the "make build" and include ol-debug.js but thats quite cumbersome for development..

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3884 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of bartvde in the comments:

run

```
npm run debug-server
```

in the ol3 folder.

This sets up a server at localhost:3000 with a loader.js file which you can reference (http://localhost:3000/loader.js) in your demo development website so that all the source code gets loaded.